# Jasmine fakeAsync tick doesn't wait for promise to be resolved

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Bellow is a small service i want to unit test (angular, jasmine, karma) which has as a goal to download a file. So i thought that what i should check is if `FileSaver.saveAs` has been called. As you can see in function 'second' there is a promise returned by `zip.generateAsync()` which i thought that by using fakeAsync and tick i could successfully wait for it to finish before code reach `expect(filesaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`. But by using console.log i verified that function second terminates after code checks for expectation and because of that the test fails.

Why by using fakeAsync and tick() test fails to wait for the promise to be resolved?

**someclass.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver/FileSaver.js';
import * as JSZip from 'jszip/dist/jszip.min';

@Injectable()
export class SomeClass {

  method2(input: any){
     const blobPart = JSON.stringify(input);
     const zip = new JSZip();
     zip.file('data', blobPart);
     zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' })
         .then( blob => {
             FileSaver.saveAs(
                 blob,
                 'randomName.dfnx'
             );
         });
  }

  method1(){
     x = 'whatever';
     this.method2(x);
  }
}
```

**someclass.service.spec.ts**

```
import {TestBed, fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {SomeClass} from './someclass.service';
const filesaver = require('file-saver/FileSaver');

describe ('Test', () => {
    let service: SomeClass;
    beforeEach( () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [SomeClass]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(SomeClass);
        spyOn(filesaver, 'saveAs').and.callThrough();
    });

    it('Test', fakeAsync( () => {
        service.method1();
        tick();
        expect(filesaver.saveAs).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Spy on **all of your functions** and mock them : don't just spy on a function you want to test.

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip/dist/jszip.min';
....
spyOn(JSZip.prototype, 'generateAsync').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('some blob'));    
spyOn(JSZip.prototype, 'file');
spyOn(filesaver, 'saveAs');
```

Your unit tests are supposed to test a single unit, and you should not rely on libraries implementations. If you mock their functions, you only focus on your own code.

Comment: You're right, i plan to do that, but why function second terminates after code checks for expectation in my example?

Comment: Don't know, I never used `tick`. I would say that the function is still running while you make your expectation, because since you didn't mock anything, the real functions are running, so they are taking some time to complete